# Plotting with Units

Tags: units

I'm trying to get *Mathematica* to plot with units, but I'm having some trouble.

Below is a minimal example of trying to plot `y = x`, where `x` is a quantity with units. Why does it only seem to work if the units are put directly into the plot function:

```
(*Define unitful constants*)
x1 = Quantity[1, "Volts"]; x2 = Quantity[2, "Volts"];
(*Try to plot, get an error*)
Plot[x, {x, x1, x2}]
(*But this works*)
Plot[x, {x, Quantity[1, "Volts"], x2}]
(*As does this*)
Plot[x, {x, x1 - Quantity[1, "Volts"], x2}]
```

There error message is

> Plot:plln: Limiting value 1V in {x, x1, x2} is not a machine-sized real number

For reference, here's what I see when I run it

[image]

[(View full)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0BPL.png)

Comment: Please copy your code into your question and indent with 4 spaces to format it. Its very hard for people to help you wiht a screen shot as they can't directly copy your code.

Comment: Sorry, I would have, but it necessarily contains Dynamic Input.  I've added the notebook itself.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I only used it because I don't like to have `Quantity[...,...]` all over for readability.  Let me rewrite the question with all "normal" code--the problem is still there.

Answer (score 10):

2 important things about `Plot`, from help:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For some reason, `Plot` is doing `Hold` on not just the first argument `x`, but also on the whole argument list, when `x1` and `x2` are `Quantity`.

When you did

```
x1 = Quantity[1, "Volts"];
x2 = Quantity[2, "Volts"];
Plot[x, {x, x1, x2}]
```

Then `Trace` shows this:

```
Plot[x, Unevaluated[{x, x1, x2}]]
```

and you can see now `x1` and `x2` have no numerical values.

But when one does this

```
x1 = 1;
x2 = 2;
Plot[x, {x, x1, x2}]
```

Then it works ofcourse, and `Trace` shows the `Hold` is doing on only the first argument `x` as expected:

```
Plot[x, {x, x1, x2}], {System`Dump`HeldOptionQ[x], 
 OptionQ[Unevaluated[x]], OptionQ[x], False
```

Now for the case that worked: When you typed

```
x1 = Quantity[1, "Volts"]; x2 = Quantity[2, "Volts"];
Plot[x, {x, Quantity[1, "Volts"], x2}]
```

This worked, because now Plot did this:

```
Plot[x, Unevaluated[{x, Quantity[1, "Volts"], Quantity[2, "Volts"]}]]
```

So the values `1` and `2` has been evaluated already inside the arguments.

Either way, it is strange and I do not know exactly why this happened. I just wanted to show more what is going on as to why `Plot` did what it did in the first case above. Either way, it has to do with evaluation of `Quantity` to a number. But I do not feel I gave an exact reason why `Plot` did what I did.

But to do what you want, you can use `QuantityMagnitude` like this

```
x1 = Quantity[1, "Volts"];
x2 = Quantity[2, "Volts"];
Plot[x, {x, QuantityMagnitude@x1, QuantityMagnitude@x2}]
```