# Units, plotting and empty plots

Tags: plotting, units

maybe I'm completely newbie but I can't understand the behavior of units and the command plot.

I'm doing some easy plotting of the state equation for gasses:

```
R =  Quantity[0.0831, ("Bars" "Liters")/("Kelvins" "Moles")];
a =  Quantity[3.658, ("Liters")^2]* Quantity[1, ("Bars")/("Moles")^2]  
b = Quantity[0.0429, ("Liters")/("Moles")]
PVW[V_, T_, N_] := ((N*R*T)/(V - N*b)) - (+a*(N^2/V^2));
```

I then test that units are ok:

```
test = PVW[Quantity[0.6, "Liters"], Quantity[270, "Kelvins"], Quantity[1, "Moles"]];
UnitSimplify[test]
```

And I get my pressure back :

```
Quantity[30.1135, "Bars"]
```

Now I want my plot so I do :

```
Plot[PVW[V, Quantity[330, "Kelvins"], Quantity[1, "Moles"] ], {V, 
Quantity[0.06, "Liters"] , Quantity[0.6, "Liters"]},
Frame -> True, 
GridLines -> None,
LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 15},
FrameLabel -> {"Volume", "Pressure"}]
```

If I evaluate that I get no errors, no nothing but a empty plot:

[image]

What is going on?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20867/plotting-with-units

Comment: -ish. (I tried that) He has an error when he plots in one way I don't (apparently, I don't know if there is an hidden trace somewhere), if I try the same solution suggested I still get the blank plot.

Comment: In fact, I get an error when I attempt to evaluate your code as is. "Plot::pllim: "Range specification {0.06,0.6} is not of the form {x, xmin, xmax}. " " - Meaning that you need `{V,Quantity[0.06, "Liters"], Quantity[0.6, "Liters"]}`, but this doesn't improve things greatly. Unfortunately, I'm completely unfamiliar with `Quantity[]`.

Comment: Well, you've got at least one syntax error (but it doesn't solve the problem): you need `{V,Quantity[0.06, "Liters"], Quantity[0.6, "Liters"]}` as your plot limits, and you probably also don't want the curly braces around `PVW` call.

Comment: Yes there was a copy paste error in the code, I edited the code.

Answer (score 3):

Still working out the **why**, but wrapping an `Evaluate[]` around your function seems to solve the problem:

```
Plot[
 Evaluate[
  PVW[V, Quantity[330, "Kelvins"], Quantity[1, "Moles"]
 ]
],
{V,Quantity[0.06, "Liters"],Quantity[0.6, "Liters"]}, 
Frame -> True, 
GridLines -> None, 
LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 15}, 
FrameLabel -> {"Volume", "Pressure"}]
```

[image: Plot]

**Edit:**

This behaviour is discussed by Nasser in [this related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20867/plotting-with-units).

**Edit 2:**

As mentioned in your comment, this problem is a little bit stranger than I'd realized. If anybody has insight as to why the following three examples return different results, feel free to chime in.

1. As above, with `Evaluate[]` around the `PVW[]` call, and units passed via the plot range specification.
2. Still using `Evaluate[]`, but with the `PlotRange[]` being just numbers, and `V` being passed through a `Quantity[]` function:

   ```
   Remove["Global`*"];
   R = Quantity[0.0831, ("Bars" "Liters")/("Kelvins" "Moles")];
   a = Quantity[3.658, ("Liters")^2]*Quantity[1, ("Bars")/("Moles")^2];
   b = Quantity[0.0429, ("Liters")/("Moles")];
   PVW[V_, T_, N_] := ((N*R*T)/(V - N*b)) - (a*(N^2/V^2));
   Plot[Evaluate[
     PVW[Quantity[V, "Liter"], Quantity[330, "Kelvins"], 
      Quantity[1, "Moles"]]], {V, 0.06, 0.6}, Frame -> True, 
    GridLines -> None, 
    LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 15}, 
    FrameLabel -> {"Volume", "Pressure"}]
   ```

   [image: second plot]
3. Using numbers without units:

   ```
   Remove["Global`*"];
   R = 0.0831;
   a = 3.658;
   b = 0.0429;
   PVW[V_, T_, N_] := ((N*R*T)/(V - N*b)) - (a*(N^2/V^2));
   Plot[PVW[V, 330, 1], {V, 0.06, 0.6}, Frame -> True, GridLines -> None,
     LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 15}, 
    FrameLabel -> {"Volume", "Pressure"}]
   ```

   [image: third plot]

Comment: It works, but it seems that If now change say the tempeature inside the evaluate PVW call it doesn't change the plot

Comment: Works for me:
`Show[Plot[
    Evaluate[
     PVW[V, Quantity[#, "Kelvins"], Quantity[1, "Moles"]]], {V, 
     Quantity[0.06, "Liters"], Quantity[0.6, "Liters"]}, 
    Frame -> True, GridLines -> None, 
    LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 15}, 
    FrameLabel -> {"Volume", "Pressure"}] & /@ Range[50, 350, 50], 
 PlotRange -> {{0.06, 0.6}, {0, 40000}}]`

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct it works. But, I honestly didn't expect that output :D  If i drop the units, I get the expected behavior!  [link](http://imgur.com/6lzInko) EDIT:with the same paramters Temperature going from 250 to 350 in step of 10

Comment: Hmm. That's really odd. I can reproduce that here, too.

Comment: Didn't realize `Quantity[]` would convert units. Replacing "Bars" with "Pascals" makes my second two examples agree. I'm still not sure why the first one is different. I can't find any examples of passing `Quantity[]` values using the plot range.

Comment: Indeed, I found that one second ago too, but still I would expect to change it back to 'bars' with:  TargetUnits -> "Bars". The first one is really strange though !

Answer (score 1):

You need `Evaluate` to release the `HoldAll` (as mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20867/plotting-with-units)):

```
Plot[Evaluate@PVW[V, Quantity[330, "Kelvins"], Quantity[1, "Moles"]],
    {V, Quantity[0.06, "Liters"], Quantity[0.6, "Liters"]}, 
    Frame -> True, GridLines -> None, 
    LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 15}, 
    FrameLabel -> {"Volume", "Pressure"}]
```

You also had a couple of typos (in an earlier version than current): you need `{V,Quantity[0.06, "Liters"], Quantity[0.6, "Liters"]}` as your plot limits, and you probably also don't want the curly braces around the `PVW` call.