# Plot3D including units

Tags: plotting, units

I am trying to plot a 3D plot with a formula containing units.
When I put the formula explicitly it works:

```
Plot3D[Quantity[V, "Centimeters"/"Seconds"]^2/ Quantity[r, "Centimeters"], {V, Quantity[40, (("Centimeters")/("Seconds"))^2],Quantity[50, (("Centimeters")/("Seconds"))^2]}, {r, Quantity[50, "Centimeters"], Quantity[58, "Centimeters"]}]
```

but as a function, I get an empty box

```
a[V_, r_] := Quantity[V, "Centimeters"/"Seconds"]^2/ Quantity[r, "Centimeters"];

Plot3D[a[V, r], {V, Quantity[40, (("Centimeters")/("Seconds"))^2], Quantity[50, (("Centimeters")/("Seconds"))^2]}, {r, Quantity[50, "Centimeters"], Quantity[58, "Centimeters"]}]
```

Can someone help what am i doing wrong?

Comment: when continued searching in the forum, I saw that inserting `Evaluate[a[V_, r_]]` solved this problem
Thanks a lot Doron https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27680/units-plotting-and-empty-plots?rq=1

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27680/units-plotting-and-empty-plots?rq=1